# fullscreen video in center of VideoView?

Tags: android, android-videoview

Right now when I'm playing a video in VideoView that is nu-proportional, video is placed at the top left corner of the VideoView...

1. is there a way to place an nu-proportional video on center of VideoView?
2. is there a way to crop and nu-proportional so that it would scale to fullscreen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `android:gravity="center"` to your VideoView inside the XML for the layout file

Answer (score 1):

There's no gravity on the videoView or at least anymore.
You can use WRAP_CONTENT for width and height put it in a relativeLayout and use centerInParent.